# Cannot reset MUI DatePicker from keydown event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I came across this weird behavior that I cannot explain. The sandbox for the code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-cannot-reset-on-keydown-event-4ndp2?file=/demo.js).

I'm trying to add the possibility to reset a `readOnly` field by pressing <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> but it does not work. While trying to reproduce the issue, I can reset it when pressing a button, but not when typing on the keyboard; why?

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDayjs from "@mui/lab/AdapterDayjs";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

import frLocaleDate from "dayjs/locale/fr";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleChanged = useCallback((newValue) => {
    setMessage("Value changed to " + newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  }, []);
  const handleInputKeyDown = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
      setMessage("Reset through handleInputKeyDown");
      setValue(null);
    }
  }, []);
  const handleReset = useCallback(() => {
    setMessage("Reset through handleReset");
    setValue(null);
  }, []);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} locale={frLocaleDate}>
      <Typography>Try pressing DEL or BACKSPACE to clear</Typography>
      <DatePicker
        clearable
        showTodayButton
        label="Basic example"
        inputFormat="LL"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChanged}
        renderInput={({ InputProps, inputProps, ...props }) => (
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            margin="dense"
            size="small"
            onKeyDown={handleInputKeyDown}
            InputProps={{ ...InputProps }}
            inputProps={{ ...inputProps, readOnly: true, placeholder: "" }}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
      <Typography>
        Debug: <pre>{message}</pre>
      </Typography>
      <Typography>
        Current value: <pre>{JSON.stringify(value)}</pre>
      </Typography>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I tried to delay the `setValue(null)` inside of the `handleInputKeyDown` function, but even if the value is `null`, the input still displays a value.

### ** Update **

The problem occurs only when the field has focus. If I change the `handleInputKeyDown` like this, press <kbd>DEL</kbd> and click away from the input field (i.e. causing it to lose focus), then the field is reset after 2 seconds (when the `setTimeout` calls the handler function).

```
const handleInputKeyDown = useCallback((event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMessage("Reset through handleInputKeyDown");
      setValue(null);
    }, 2000);
  }
}, []);
```

I tried adding a ref to the `DatePicker` component, then calling `ref.current.blur();`, but it does not work, and the element does not lose focus.

### ** Update 2 **

Following Emanuele Scarabattoli's answer and explanation, this also seems to work in my particular case :

```
const handleInputKeyDown = useCallback((event) => {
  //event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.blur();  // blur outside the scope of keyDown
      setMessage("Reset through handleInputKeyDown");
      setValue(null);
    }, 0);
  }
}, []);
```

Which raises this other issue : When the field is focused, changing the value will not update the display. This is problematic when the user selects the field, but the program updates it programmatically; the values gets updated but the user does not have a feedback of the changes.

Comment: I previously provided a wrong answer (then deleted), now I completely changed it and, it is working (at least by changing the code in the snippet you provided).

Comment: About the last update, my suggestion is to conditionally the `blur` and `preventDefault` depending on the `keyCode`. Let me know if this will work, so I can update the answer.

Comment: It seems that both solutions (using `event.preventDefault()` and deferring `event.target.blur()`) seem to be working for both <kbd>DEL</kbd> and <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> so it's fine for the time being. Both issues have been posted on Github about it (not provided so I'm not cross posting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your suggestion in the update, I got this workaround:

```
const handleInputKeyDown = useCallback((event) => {
  event.target.blur() // As you suggested
  event.preventDefault() // This does the trick
  if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
    setMessage("Reset through handleInputKeyDown");
    setValue(null);
  }
}, [setMessage, setValue]); // Better to add, as per React documentation
```

**Possible explanation**

**Disclaimer: this explanation is not demonstrated and it is not necessarily true!**

Since the `DEL` key, as default behavior, is used as a key to delete a character, my impression is that the default behavior have to be prevented to make it work differently. Probably this is due to something related to `event.target.value` in the `event`. I mean, possibly, the browser, in case of `DEL` or `ESC` pressed, is propagating an event that, at the end, does something like `valueOfTheInput = event.target.value`, even if the `value` itself is not changed, so we need to avoid this.

Comment: Excellent! Now I'm curious to know what's going on and why `event.preventDefault()` is necessary! :D

Comment: @YanickRochon, you have no idea how much time it taken hahaha Well, since the `DEL` is working as a key to delete a character (as usual), my impression is that the default behavior have to be prevented to make it work differently. Probably due to something related to `event.target.value` in the event. Let me add this explanation in the answer. This stuff was killing me, I had to find an answer XD

Comment: I added *Update 2* to my question. It's not needed to answer, but still a severe issue to me with that component.

Comment: Check the comment to the question :)